# preorder array from binary tree

Tags: c, recursion, binary-tree, preorder

I cannot seem to get this function to work. It is supposed to find the preorder of a given binary tree, and put those integers into an array. This function was adapted from a similar print preorder traversal that can be found on geeksforgeeks.

```
//node struct
typedef struct node
{
    // Each node holds a single integer.
    int data;

    // Pointers to the node's left and right children.
    struct node *left, *right;
} node;

node *create_node(int data)
{
    node *n = calloc(1, sizeof(node));
    n->data = data;
    return n;
}

unsigned int node_count_recursive(node *root)
{
    unsigned int count = 1;
    if (root->left != NULL)
      count += node_count_recursive(root->left);
    if (root->right != NULL)
      count += node_count_recursive(root->right);
    return count;
}

unsigned int node_count(node *root)
{
    unsigned int count = 0;
    if (root != NULL)
      count = node_count_recursive(root);
    return count;
}

// helper function that takes in the root, a dynamically allocated array, and count variable
// initialized to 0
// problem I believe is in this function
unsigned int preorder_helper(node *root, int *array, unsigned int count)
{
    if (root == NULL)
        return 0;
    // This does not work
    array[count++] = root->data;
    count = preorder_helper(root->left, array, count);
    count = preorder_helper(root->right, array, count);

  return count;
}

// creates dynamically allocated array for helper function.
int *preorder_array(node *root)
{
  int *array = malloc(sizeof(node) * node_count(root));
  preorder_helper(root, array, 0);
  return array;
}

// creates tree
int main(void)
{
    node *root1;
    int *preArray;

    root1 = create_node(23);
    root1->left = create_node(12);
    root1->left->left = create_node(5);
    root1->left->right = create_node(18);
    root1->right = create_node(71);
    root1->right->right = create_node(56);
 
    // points preArray pointer to function
    preArray = preorder_array(root1);
  
  // loops through each integer in array
  for (int i = 0; i < node_count(root1); i++) //node_count counts nodes in tree
    printf("%d ", preArray[i]);

  return 0;
}
```

The preorder_helper function seems to get the first 2 or 3 correct preorder values, but then the rest of the array is 0. The output of this code is this:
56 12 5 0 0 0

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Please show the `create_node` function, `node_count` function and any other missing functions. The code needs to be complete and runnable exactly as shown. At a guess: the node pointers are not all initialised correctly.

Comment: `count = preorder_helper(root->left, array, count);` That looks wrong. Because the terminating condition for the recursion returns 0. That will cause some branches of the recursion to incorrectly start writes at index 0 of the array.

Comment: @kaylum I put an if statement that if the left or right != NULL, then call the recursive functions. That, however, just prints the nodes in the order they were inserted

Comment: The terminating condition of the recursion should return `count` ; not zero.

Comment: So suppose you have  a tree with 2 nodes, root and root->right. The preorder array should have them in that order. Where the number for root->right will be in fact stored? Look at your `return 0` statement, do you think it has something to do with that?

Comment: @WhozCraig Returning count and not zero seems to just print the nodes in the order that they are inserted in, not in preorder

Comment: What do you mean by "in the order that they are inserted in"? Because it looks to me that the insertion order is in fact pre-order so that would be the right result. What exact result are you getting after that change?

Comment: @idkusrname126 The code I'm referring to, `preorder_helper` doesn't print anything, so I have no idea what you're talking about. That's the base-case and function I'm referring to.

Comment: You guys are right, I forgot the nodes were inserted in pre-order.